# SQL: primary key of 2 fields - with one field having auto increment enabled

Tags: mysql, sql, primary-key, auto-increment

I am trying to set up a database and got stuck with the following SQL-Code:

```
CREATE TABLE user
(
mandt       int(4) unsigned zerofill not null,
user_id     int auto_increment not null,
name        varchar(64),
firstname   varchar(64),
password    varchar(256),
email       varchar(128),
active      boolean,
primary key (mandt, user_id),
foreign key (mandt) references customer(mandt) on update cascade on delete restrict
);
```

What I am trying to achieve is to have a primary key, containing the fields `mandt, user_id`. `mandt` is a foreign key and therefore only the `user_id` needs auto_increment.

However, if i try to run the above SQL-Statement (in PhpMyAdmin) I get the following error:

> 1075 - Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

As soon as I remove the AI from user_id it works.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: Why do you need `mandt` as part of your key if `user_id` is guaranteed to be a unique identifier for the row (and it's even called "id", supposedly for a reason)?

Comment: Can you describe the relationship between this table and the `customer` table?

Comment: It's intended to act like the "client" (or mandt [german]) field in an SAP ERP. It helps to keep the records from multiple usergroups (like companies) seperated from each other. To guarantee that an admin from company A cannot see the user records from company B we use thies field.
BTW: It just is for a university project so dont worry about security too much :)

Comment: The customer Table contains just same master data like phone number and the address for the different customers. Its cardinality is n:1. Furthermore the primary key (mandt) in customer is used for the above mentioned purpose. Hope this clarifies everything

Comment: Is it your intention for user_id to be unique within a single client/mandt, or globally?

Comment: In short: Within a single client/mandt. Yes. So duplicate user_ids might exist globally.
However meanwhile I see the problem. So this question can be considered as "answered".
Howver: Thank you guys!